# Github shows a wrong commit diff

Tags: git, github, diff

when I lookup this commit in github, it shows me that a single file has changed:

https://github.com/opensupports/opensupports/commit/2aded07b568cba44ccbe2259fe6984c543ee2353

but when I clone the repo and use

```
git diff --name-only 10adc62d9070fbc69dfb55d7575bf950df793bc1 2aded07b568cba44ccbe2259fe6984c543ee2353
```

it will show me 3 changed files:

> ```
> client/src/app-components/ticket-event.js
> client/src/app-components/ticket-event.scss
> server/controllers/ticket/comment.php
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing a difference because 10adc62 is not the parent commit.  GitHub is showing you the commits in the order that they were created, but the parent of 2aded07b (and 10adc62) is 33bf2c4.  So when you do a diff, you're actually comparing two different divergent branches that were later merged together.

If you want to diff against a parent commit at the command line, regardless of what it's called, you can just write the revision with a caret at the end, like this: `2aded07b^`.  That, of course, will only work if you have only one parent.

Answer (score 2):

2aded07b568cba's parent is *not* 10adc62d9070fb, it's 33bf2c4. So there are other changes from other revisions between 10adc62d9070f and 2aded07b568cba44cc modifying other files.